# Checksumming filepaths that may not be ascii

Tags: python

Let's say I have two filepaths:

```
/my/file/path.mov
/mé/fileé/pathé.mov
```

If I do something like:

```
{hashlib.md5(path).hexdigest() for path in paths}
```

Then I'll sometimes get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 217: ordinal not in range(128)

My quickfix was something along the lines of:

```
{hashlib.md5(path).hexdigest() for path in paths if path.isascii()}
```

But what would be a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Must be Python 2 (the `u'\xc1'` gives it away).  It defaults encoding to `ascii` if you don't do it yourself. Python 3 *requires* encoding to a byte string if you start with a Unicode string because you can only hash bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `encoding` that you have to give it is missing.
`utf -...` followed by the number of the encode you want to use ...

Normally it should be fine like this:

```
hashlib.md5(path.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an encoding yourself. In full generality, you can use UTF-8.

```
hashlib.md5(path.encode("utf-8"))
```